# Sum org-mode table column based on other column

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I have this org-mode table:

```
| Category         | Category Budget | Needs Transfer |
|------------------+-----------------+----------------|
| Rent             |            3000 | t              |
| Internet         |             125 | t              |
| Food             |            1000 |                |
| Coffee           |             500 |                |
| Cellphone        |             120 | t              |
| Cigarettes       |             100 |                |
| Total            |            9945 |                |
```

I want the "Total" row, in the "Needs Transfer" column, to show the sum of all of the budgets that have "t" in their "Needs Transfer" column.

I already tried this solution to no avail:

```
@>$3 = '(apply '+ '(org-lookup-all "t" '(@2$3..@-1$3) '(@2$2..@-1$2) 'string=));E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it: you have quoted the `org-lookup-call` which prevents its evaluation; and you need to convert the strings in the second list to numbers in order to add them together. This works for me:

```
#+TBLFM: @>$3 = '(apply '+ (org-lookup-all "t" '(@2$3..@-1$3)  (mapcar #'string-to-number '(@2$2..@-1$2)) 'string=));E
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `orgtbl-aggregate` package available on http://melpa.org

Give a name to your table, for instance

```
#+name: mytable
```

Then create an aggregation block with `C-c C-x i`

```
#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "mytable" :cols "'Needs Transfer' vsum('Category Budget')"
| 'Needs Transfer' | vsum('Category Budget') |
|------------------+-------------------------|
| t                |                    3245 |
|                  |                   11545 |
#+END:
```

You get the sum for rows with `t`, and as a bonus the sum of rows without `t`.